# Extracting N numbers into a new column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column ID which is composed by `10` numbers or `7` numbers. I would like to create a new column that will contain the last 3 numbers/digits  if Column ID contains len=10, otherwise I would like to keep the number that was in column ID.

```
DF['ID']= ['5487123500', '6287467', '5487123240', '6366584', '5487123260' ]
```

OUTCOME:

```
DF['NEW_ID']= ['500', '6287467', '240', '6366584', '260']
```

I have tried with re and lambas but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### One line solution

```
df['NEW_ID']  =  df['ID'].apply(lambda x : x[-3:] if len(x)==10 else x)
```

Comment: Performance of `apply` is slower when compared to `np.where`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) to check the `length` of each value:

```
In [869]: df
Out[869]: 
           ID
0  5487123500
1     6287467
2  5487123240
3     6366584
4  5487123260

In [872]: import numpy as np

In [873]: df['new ID'] = np.where(df['ID'].str.len().eq(10), df['ID'].str[-3:], df['ID'])

In [874]: df
Out[874]: 
           ID   new ID
0  5487123500      500
1     6287467  6287467
2  5487123240      240
3     6366584  6366584
4  5487123260      260
```

**EDIT:** If your `ID` column is `int`, then do this:

```
In [881]: df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)
In [873]: df['new ID'] = np.where(df.ID.str.len().eq(10), df.ID.str[-3:], df.ID)
```

Comment: It looks good but I have the following error: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: This answer is much better like accepted, plus1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
DF['ID']= ['5487123500', '6287467', '5487123240', '6366584', '5487123260' ]

def filter_id(inp):
    res = list()
    for val in inp:
        if len(val) >= 10:
           return val[-3:]
        else:
           return val

DF['NEW_ID']= DF[['ID']].apply(filter_id,axis=1)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. I tried it and it shows me the following error: 
TypeError: filter_id() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: Yeah , realised that , updated the code to make it work now